When to use stateful service instead of stateless service with remote cache like Redis
Stateless service with remote cache like Redis will provide functionality simiar to that of having stateless service. With stateless service the complications of configuring load balancers to use sticky sessions goes away and scaling horizontally becomes very easy. So I'm not clear when to use stateful service instead of stateless service with remote cache like Redis?
The only scenario I could think of is to save cache server cost. Are there any more usecases which I am missing?

The wording of your question is a bit unclear, but if I understand correctly, you should implement caching whether your app is stateless or stateful. In my opinion, opting for a stateless architecture is preferable as it minimizes dependencies and allows for easier scaling.

Staeful means you use the local servers ram for storing cache. For eg a users shopping cart will be stored in local ram instead of remote cache.
